# Generic Sort by related object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sorting, expression

I´m using this great generic sort helper from Mr. Cincura (http://blog.cincura.net/229310-sorting-in-iqueryable-using-string-as-column-name/) to sort records returned from SQL server using Entity Framework

```
 private static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderingHelper<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, bool descending, bool anotherLevel)
    {
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), string.Empty); // I don't care about some naming
        MemberExpression property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
        LambdaExpression sort = Expression.Lambda(property, param);
        MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            (!anotherLevel ? "OrderBy" : "ThenBy") + (descending ? "Descending" : string.Empty),
            new[] { typeof(T), property.Type },
            source.Expression,
            Expression.Quote(sort));
        return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);
    }
```

The problem is it works form any property of the object but not for the properties of a related object. if I have

```
public foo FOO;

public class foo
        {
            public string name {get;set};
            public bar Bar {get;set;}

    }

    public class bar
    {
        public string name {get;set;}
    }
```

I can sort by **FOO.name** but not by **FOO.Bar.name** but not by foo.Bar.name.

I think I have to associate another expression but my attempts so far yielded no results. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: this would be a lot more readable, if you used class and variable names which didn't only differ by casing. Futhermore, show how you created the `IQueryable` and used `OrderingHelper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the nested member expression yourself, for example, by splitting propertyName-parameter and looping through it:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderingHelper<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, bool descending, bool anotherLevel)
{
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), string.Empty); // I don't care about some naming

    Expression body = param;
    foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))
    {
        body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member);
    }

    LambdaExpression sort = Expression.Lambda(body, param);
    MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        (!anotherLevel ? "OrderBy" : "ThenBy") + (descending ? "Descending" : string.Empty),
        new[] { typeof(T), body.Type },
        source.Expression,
        Expression.Quote(sort));

    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but it seems to work only when the source is a DbSet<T>. 
if the input is a (for example) an EntityQueryable (created by applying a "Where" to a DbSet<T>) an InvalidOperationException is raised with the message "No generic method 'ThenByDescending' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic. "

Answer (score 0):

Make bar comparable

```
    public class bar : IComparable
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(object other)
        {
            return this.name.CompareTo(((bar)other).name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to support property path, replace the line

```
MemberExpression property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
```

with

```
var property = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)param, Expression.PropertyOrField);
```